# If else statement in bat

Tags: batch-file

The code below checks if there is a folder called Made_files if so it will cd to that folder and make a new file using variables
Else it will make a folder called Made_files THEN cd to that folder and run the code but at the moment all it does is flash up then close instantlly can someone help

```
if EXIST Made_files (
cd Made_files
set /p name=Name of file:-
set /p Filetype=Type of file(txt, bat js):-
echo @echo off > %name%.%Filetype%
echo color 0a >> %name%.%Filetype%
) else mkdir Made_files
cd Made_files
set /p name=Name of file:-
set /p Filetype=Type of file(txt, bat js):-
echo @echo off > %name%.%Filetype%
echo color 0a >> %name%.%Filetype%
echo ___
pause
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: Ask for filename and type

set /p name=Name of file:-
set /p Filetype=Type of file(txt, bat js):-

:: Required file to be located in "Made_files"
SET "subdir=Made_files"
MD ".\%subdir%" 2>NUL
CD "%subdir%"
(
 echo @echo off
 echo color 0a
)> %name%.%Filetype%

echo ___
pause 

GOTO :EOF
```

What your code does:

If the subdirectory already exists, switch to that directory, ask for the filename&type, then create a new file using the requested data. Otherwise, create the directory.

*THEN*

Change to the subdirectory again (so if `made_files` already existed, try to change to `.\made_files\made_files`), ask for the filename and type and create the file.

===

**BUT** Please read [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947). Since you are not using `delayedexpansion`, when the `if` statement is parsed (and the `if` statement continues until the end of the `else` clause) the values of the variables `name` and `filetype` are replaced by their values when the statement was parsed (~verified), **NOT** as they were input, so the destination filename will be *nothing*.*nothing* , which is `"."` - a directory-name (sort-of).

It's likely that this is the source of the drama.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.

===

So : the code I suggest:

1. Asks for the file name and type.
2. Attempts to make the directory. If it already exists, this will generate an errormessage which is suppressed by the `2>nul`.
3. switches to that subdirectory.
4. Creates the file.

Note that if the `echo`es are surrounded by parentheses, then their output is combined and directed to the file, saving a plethora of redirect-to-file clauses.